# Mongodb include null in array query results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB document like this

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("53ea4bcb311164af033743fd")
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Paul"
      "age": 36
    },
    null,
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "age": 74
    }
  ]
}
```

I might not have been the best design choice, but i decided to use the index of the array as the userKey. 
Now I wanted to improve the performance of my queries and just use the fields necessary in my query projection, so the query looks like this:

```
db.accounts.findOne('53ea4bcb311164af033743fd', {'users.name': 1});
```

This returns

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("53ea4bcb311164af033743fd")
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Paul"
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now is there any way of including the `null` as well, so the index is correct? I know it works with just using the projection `{'users': 1}`, but this is not performing well enough for me, because there are quite a lot of values inside my user object.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in your question, this might not be the most suitable implementation for your use case considering your array doesn't have homogeneous objects stored but nulls and documents.

Your findOne command doesn't bring the null values because you are requesting for the field named "name" inside every object of the array field.

The implementation of the 1:N relation by embedding the documents with fields 'name' and 'age' is a risky and fragile decision that might lead to exceeding the maximum document size of 16MB as explained in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/).

It will be useful to know more about your application and the usage of the collection you refer to in order to fully understand what you are implementing and suggest further.

Comment: Thanks Enrique! The 16MB limit is not a big concern for me, because every account has its own document and users associated with it - and there is a limit on maximum users. For now i solved the issue by adding keys to the users and referring to these. Some refactoring was required, but still the best solution for my problem i guess.